# Users are not able to see Queue name if the owner of the record is a queue

Tags: queue, record-owner

If the record has an owner as a queue, then some users are not able to see the queue name. Instead, they are able to see _.
Please see the attached screenshot. The user was able to see the queue name before. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Is the user in question able to see the queue? This strikes me as a permissions issue.

Comment: see this KI - https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BRTQA2 - possible issue; or this https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000eWDd; or https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000eWDnQAM; try in Classic, then compare to LEX